# Desabilitar Modo de Exibição Vba Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como Desabilitar Modo de Exibição pelo Vba Excel.

Queria que ao abrir a planilha o usuário já viesse com esse recurso habilitado

Answer (score 1):

Este código do [Mr Excel](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/631545-change-trust-center-settings-vba.html) guarda o estado de segurança da planilha na variável `lSecurity`, depois muda para o nível de segurança baixo `msoAutomationSecurityLow` e depois retorna para o nível de segurança original.

```
Public Sub Subrotina()
    Dim lSecurity As Long

    On Error GoTo Fechar

    lSecurity = Application.AutomationSecurity
    Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityLow

    '''''''''''''''''''''
    '   Código aqui     '
    '''''''''''''''''''''

Fechar:
    Application.AutomationSecurity = lSecurity
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Só ir nas opções. Arquivo->Opções. Ajustar na Central de confiabilidade.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Oi, obrigado, eu queria fazer isso, mas pelo VBA, sem a internveção do usuário